# Using FluentMongo to remove and update documents

Tags: mongodb, fluent-mongo

I was wondering if anyone has a clean way to handle removing and updating documents using FluentMongo?

I am creating a repository layer using FluentMongo; however, not being able to remove or update documents is proving troublesome. Perhaps I missed a way to handle this while maintaining a proper repository pattern?

```cs
public interface IRepository : IDisposable
{
    IQueryable<T> All<T>() where T : class, new();

    void Delete<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
        where T : class, new();

    void Update<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class, new();
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way will be to wrap the standard MongoCollection behind your repository methods.  Since your repository is typed you can just create a typed collection and remove the documents from that collection.  Here is a sample implementation.

```cs
 MongoCollection<T> collection = mongoserver.GetCollection<T>();

 public void Delete(string id)
 {   
      this.collection.Remove(Query.EQ("_id", id));
 }

 public void Delete(T entity)
 {
     this.Delete(entity.Id);
 }
```

---

added by *[balexandre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28004/balexandre)* on 27 July 2013

using [FluentMongo](https://github.com/craiggwilson/fluent-mongo), there a property that retrieves the `MongoCollection<T>` that is useful for advanced queries, for example, if we want to delete all our documents in our collection, we would write something like this:

```cs
public void DeleteAll() {
    var collection = myRepository.Collection;
    collection.RemoveAll();
}
```

if you want to return a confirmation that all documents were indeed deleted use the `Ok` property

```cs
public bool DeleteAll() {
    var collection = myRepository.Collection;
    return collection.RemoveAll().Ok;
}
```

Comment: How about for the Delete with the Linq expression? That's the real issue; creating the query.